# Hierarchical cluster analysis help - dendrogram

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I made a code to generate a dendrogram as you can see in the image, using the `hclust` function. So, I would like help in the interpretation of this dendrogram. Note that the locations of these points are close. What does this dendrogram result I'm having mean, can you help me? **I would really like a more complete analysis of the generated output**.

```
library(geosphere)

Points_properties<-structure(list(Propertie=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29), Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
                                               -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996, 
                                               -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376, 
                                               -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422, 
                                               -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902, 
                                               -24.785587, -24.787558), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
                                                                                                  -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095, 
                                                                                                  -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657, 
                                                                                                  -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435, 
                                                                                                  -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141, 
                                                                                                  -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "data.frame"))

coordinates<-subset(Points_properties,select=c("Latitude","Longitude"))
plot(coordinates[,2:1])
text(x = Points_properties$Longitude,
y= Points_properties$Latitude, labels=Points_properties$Propertie, pos=2)
```

[image]

```
d<-distm(coordinates[,2:1])
d<-as.dist(d)
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")
plot(fit.average,hang=-1,cex=.8, main = "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You chose to perform hierarchical clustering using `average` method.

According to `?hclust`:

> This function performs a hierarchical cluster analysis using a set of dissimilarities for the *n* objects being clustered. Initially, each object is assigned to its own cluster and then **the algorithm proceeds iteratively, at each stage joining the two most similar clusters, continuing until there is just a single cluster**. At each stage distances between clusters are recomputed

You can follow what happens using the `merge` field:

> Row *i* of merge describes the merging of clusters at step *i* of the clustering. If an element *j* in the row is negative, then observation *−j* was merged at this stage. If *j* is positive then the merge was with the cluster formed at the (earlier) stage *j* of the algorithm

```
fit.average$merge
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  -21  -22
 [2,]  -15    1
 [3,]  -13  -24
 [4,]   -6  -20
 [5,]   -2  -23
 [6,]  -16  -27
...
```

This is what you see in the dendogram:
[image]

The height on the y-axis of the dendogram represents the distance between a point and the center of the cluster it's associated to (because you use method `average`).

1. points 21 and 22 (which are the nearest) are merged together creating cluster 1 with their barycenter
2. cluster 1 is merged with point 15 creating cluster 2
3. ...

You could then call `rect.clust` which allows various arguments, like the number of groups `k` you'd like:

```
rect.hclust(fit.average, k=3)
```

[image]

You can also use output of `rect.clust` to color the original points:

```
groups <- rect.hclust(fit.average, k=3)
groups

#[[1]]
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 17 18 19 20

#[[2]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4 15 21 22 23

#[[3]]
#  [1] 11 12 13 14 16 24 25 26 27 28 29

colors <- rep(1:length(groups),lengths(groups))
colors <- colors[order(unlist(groups))]

plot(coordinates[,2:1],col = colors)
```

[image]